# Duplicate symbol in Cordova iOS build

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm running a PhoneGap project using in app purchase. I've been building my app fine, until I enabled the Audiotoolbox framework under 'Link binary with libraries' in Xcode. Now I get the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_InAppPurchase.unfinishedTransactions in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_InAppPurchase.list in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_InAppPurchase.retainer in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BatchProductsRequestDelegate.plugin in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BatchProductsRequestDelegate.command in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BatchProductsRequestDelegate in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BatchProductsRequestDelegate in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_InAppPurchase in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_InAppPurchase in:
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-5FA8967824755833.o
/Users/joy/Sites/phrase/platforms/ios/build/Pop Phrase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pop Phrase.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase-8597B14B285C1761.o
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I assume I have a variable duplicated somewhere, but not sure where. The files the error references do not exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by removing the plugin completely and re-adding it. iOS is weird.

Answer (score 6):

**Important (since cordova-ios 4.5.0):**

Please note, that the cordova plugin *cordova-plugin-console* is now part of the cordova-ios platform.
So if you're using cordova-ios@4.5.0 or higher absolutely **remove cordova-plugin-console!**

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

This concerns plain cordova apps and ionic apps as well.
Further information: [Console-Plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: for cordova-ios@4.4.0 ??

Comment: for cordova-ios@4.5.4??